# Monitor UI latency of web app from javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, monitoring

How can I best monitor UI latency of my webapp from Javascript? Specifically, I'm looking for monitoring that could be built into the application itself such that instances of the application, running on computers across the internet, would report back as to how latent their UI is.

In [this Google I/O talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKNXidK5HZsHu9T7zs6nxwK), they discuss tracking down memory leaks, and at 19:15, show a graph comparing memory consumption to UI latency. They dont really get into how they measure latency and run out of time at the end of the talk just as an audience member asks this question. But this leaves me thinking that there must be a way!

Answer (score 0):

Well in simple terms, you measure the aggregate time of your UI functions, then divide by the number of calls :-)

**reliable UI timing:**

But, in all seriousness, this doesn't always work nicely. The reason is that certain operations are synchronous from the POV of JavaScript, but don't in fact update the DOM synchronously in practice.

I've found that the best way to measure real-ish UI update time is to start measuring --  `(new Date()).getTime()` -- at the start of my UI update function, then at the end of it make a call to `window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){ /* get elapsed time here! */ })`;

[window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) is fairly new, so older browsers don't really support it.

There's also some intrinsic time that elapses even if your update code does nothing, but you can measure this by using a tight loop with the above approach in your page startup code.

**relaying back to the server:**

I would asynchronously add the timing results to a queue. Then when youre main code isn't doing much (and/or periodically) send the results back to your server via AJAX as an array. (including your 'empty' baseline benchmark). Then you can process the results server-side.